# Issue with code for handling multiple leaf nodes in nested dictionay

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, recursion

I've the following code  :

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [8567, None, None, None],
    [8596, 8595, None, 5033],
    [8576, 8571, None, 447],
    [8576, 8571, -1879674.00, 152],
    [8576, 8571, 2971934.78, 152],
    [8576, 8571, -21044.15, 150],
    [8577, 8571, None, 5047],
    [8574, 8569, 7807810.50, 329688],
    [8575, 8569, None, 3734],
    [8573, 8568, None, 414397],
    [8572, 8568, 12234723.90, 336487],
    [8571, 8567, None, None],
    [8569, 8567, None, None],
    [8568, 8567, None, None],
    [8595, 8567, None, None]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["HIERARCHYNODEID", "PARENTNODEID", "HVALUE", "IDs"])
df = df.fillna(0)

def build_dict(df):
    hierarchy_dict = {}
    root_nodes = df[df['PARENTNODEID'] == 0]
    for _, r in root_nodes.iterrows():
        hierarchy_dict[r['HIERARCHYNODEID']] = build_dict_helper(df, r['HIERARCHYNODEID'])
    return hierarchy_dict

def build_dict_helper(df, parent):
    children = df[df['PARENTNODEID'] == parent]
    node = {"HVALUE": 0, "IDs": []}
    child_nodes = {}
    for _, r in children.iterrows():
        child_node = build_dict_helper(df, r['HIERARCHYNODEID'])
        node["HVALUE"] += r["HVALUE"] + child_node["HVALUE"]
        node["IDs"].extend([r["IDs"]] + child_node["IDs"])  
        if r["HIERARCHYNODEID"] in child_nodes:
            existing_child = child_nodes[r["HIERARCHYNODEID"]]
            existing_child["HVALUE"] += r["HVALUE"] + child_node["HVALUE"]
            existing_child["IDs"].extend([r["IDs"]] + child_node["IDs"]) 
        else:
            child_nodes[r['HIERARCHYNODEID']] = child_node
    if child_nodes:
        node.update(child_nodes)
    return node

def create_named_dict(df):
    dct = build_dict(df)
    return dct

result = create_named_dict(df)
print(result)
```

The results of this code doesn't match what I need to achieve :

{8567.0: {'HVALUE': 21113751.03, 'IDs': [0.0, 447.0, 152.0, 152.0, 150.0, 5047.0, 0.0, 329688.0, 3734.0, 0.0, 414397.0, 336487.0, 0.0, 5033.0], 8571.0: {'HVALUE': 1071216.63, 'IDs': [447.0, 152.0, 152.0, 150.0, 5047.0], 8576.0: {'HVALUE': 1071216.63 , 'IDs': [152,152,150]}, 8577.0: {'HVALUE': 0 , 'IDs': [5047]}}, 8569.0: {'HVALUE': 7807810.5, 'IDs': [329688.0, 3734.0], 8574.0: {'HVALUE': 7807810.5 , 'IDs': [329688]}, 8575.0: {'HVALUE': 0 , 'IDs': [3734]}}, 8568.0: {'HVALUE': 12234723.9, 'IDs': [414397.0, 336487.0], 8573.0: {'HVALUE': 0 , 'IDs': [414397.0]}, 8572.0: {'HVALUE': 12234723.9 , 'IDs': [336487]}}, 8595.0: {'HVALUE': 0.0, 'IDs': [5033.0], 8596.0: {'HVALUE': 0, 'IDs': []}}}}

The issue for example my code gives :
8568.0: {'HVALUE': 12234723.9, 'IDs': [414397.0, 336487.0], 8573.0: {'HVALUE': 0, 'IDs': **[]**}, 8572.0: {'HVALUE': **0**, 'IDs': **[]**}}

but the expected values are :
8568.0: {'HVALUE': 12234723.9, 'IDs': [414397.0, 336487.0], 8573.0: {'HVALUE': 0 , 'IDs': **[414397.0]**}, 8572.0: {'HVALUE': **12234723.9** , 'IDs': **[336487]**}}

It's important to know that the data here is an small sample, we can have multiple leaf nodes and sub dicts, the idea is to have generic function to handle all type of nested dicts, Can anyone please help ? thanks

Comment: suggest that you shorten your input data to just include the 8568 row and its descendants and change 8568's parent to be `none` for the test, and add some print outs or use a debugger to see what you are doing wrong.  It seems like you are learning to code or learning to use pandas.

Comment: I think your data is wrong or inconsistent.  `8596`'s "IDs" is empty but seems like it should contain `5033`

Comment: it would be helpful if you nicely formatted your JSON output as Swifty did, and if you could put into words what you are expecting to happen instead of just asking us to assume whats happening based upon the output and your admittedly incorrect code.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented what you wanted (if I understood correctly, the HVALUE sum for a node should include it's own value, and the IDs list its own Id), simplified a bit the recursive helper, and removed the totally useless `create_named_dict` function:

```
def build_dict(df):
    hierarchy_dict = {}
    root_nodes = df[df['PARENTNODEID'] == 0]
    for _, r in root_nodes.iterrows():
        hierarchy_dict[r['HIERARCHYNODEID']] = build_dict_helper(df, r)
    return hierarchy_dict

def build_dict_helper(df, parent):
    children = df[df['PARENTNODEID'] == parent['HIERARCHYNODEID']]
    node = {"HVALUE": parent['HVALUE'], "IDs": [parent['IDs']]}
    for _, r in children.iterrows():
        child_dict = build_dict_helper(df, r)
        node["HVALUE"] +=  child_dict["HVALUE"]
        node["IDs"].extend(child_dict["IDs"])
        existing_values = node.get(r['HIERARCHYNODEID'], {'HVALUE': 0, 'IDs': []})
        child_dict['HVALUE'] += existing_values['HVALUE']
        child_dict['IDs'].extend(existing_values['IDs'])
        node.setdefault(r['HIERARCHYNODEID'], {}).update(child_dict)
    return node

result = build_dict(df)
print(result)
```

Result:

```
{8567.0: 
   {'HVALUE': 21113751.03, 
    'IDs': [0.0, 0.0, 447.0, 152.0, 152.0, 150.0, 5047.0, 0.0, 329688.0, 3734.0, 0.0, 414397.0, 336487.0, 0.0, 5033.0], 
    8571.0: 
       {'HVALUE': 1071216.63, 
        'IDs': [0.0, 447.0, 152.0, 152.0, 150.0, 5047.0], 
        8576.0: {'HVALUE': 1071216.63, 'IDs': [150.0, 152.0, 152.0, 447.0]}, 
        8577.0: {'HVALUE': 0.0, 'IDs': [5047.0]}
       }, 
    8569.0: 
       {'HVALUE': 7807810.5, 
        'IDs': [0.0, 329688.0, 3734.0], 
        8574.0: {'HVALUE': 7807810.5, 'IDs': [329688.0]}, 
        8575.0: {'HVALUE': 0.0, 'IDs': [3734.0]}
       }, 
    8568.0: 
       {'HVALUE': 12234723.9, 
        'IDs': [0.0, 414397.0, 336487.0], 
        8573.0: {'HVALUE': 0.0, 'IDs': [414397.0]}, 
        8572.0: {'HVALUE': 12234723.9, 'IDs': [336487.0]}
       }, 
    8595.0: 
       {'HVALUE': 0.0, 
        'IDs': [0.0, 5033.0], 
        8596.0: {'HVALUE': 0.0, 'IDs': [5033.0]}
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I fixed my HIERARCHYNODEID / IDs mix-up,  and implemented the management of multiple nodes with the same HIERARCHYID that I had overlooked.

Comment: your answer is wrong for the `8576` tree. the `HVALUE` is not `-21044.15` its `1071216.63` you are not handling the multiple children with same ID case right.. `node[r['HIERARCHYNODEID']] = child_dict` is incorrect.

Comment: also the loading of `pid` into the node's ID's is also wrong.

Comment: still is off, you have an extra 0 in all the ID's now. makes me think their may be issue with how they are doing ID's. That ID should only be initially populated if its non empty perhaps? kinda unclear becuase  of the low quality IMHO of the post for clarity of what he expects.  he just posts output instead of saying in words what should happen to the data.

Comment: I agree; I only adressed the problem mentioned in the OP (node dict missing its own data), but more info should be provided.

Comment: I still like your contribution greatly. especially you put a caveat in about the `IDs` bit. I think its different but I also greatly appreciate how you formatted the json output and put more effort into that then I did.  If you had explained the changes in addition to the code I would likely not have answered.

Answer (score 0):

Your base case seems confused and wrong.  When you construct the initial node in `build_dict_helper` you should initialize the `HVALUE` and `IDs` list with that node's values for the two fields otherwise childless nodes never get the values populated. And then as a result you don't need to keep adding `r`'s values to the childrens values in the loop, you just add in the child node's values.
Additionally it is a little quirky with regard to the `IDs` field which seems to only contain values of children plus your value if your value is not EMPTY.

As I think both explanation and code are important here is the code, just for the build_dict and build_dict_helper that has to change:

```py
def build_dict(df):
    hierarchy_dict = {}
    root_nodes = df[df['PARENTNODEID'] == 0]
    for _, r in root_nodes.iterrows():
        hierarchy_dict[r['HIERARCHYNODEID']] = build_dict_helper(df, r) # passing whole 'r'
    return hierarchy_dict

def build_dict_helper(df, parent):
    children = df[df['PARENTNODEID'] == parent['PARENTNODEID']
    node = {"HVALUE": parent["HVALUE"], "IDs": parent["IDs"] == None ? [] : [parent["IDs"]]}
    child_nodes = {}
    for _, r in children.iterrows():
        child_node = build_dict_helper(df, r['HIERARCHYNODEID'])
        node["HVALUE"] += child_node["HVALUE"]
        if child_node["IDs"].empty():
            node["IDs"].extend(None)
        else  
            node["IDs"].extend(child_node["IDs"])  
        if r["HIERARCHYNODEID"] in child_nodes:
            existing_child = child_nodes[r["HIERARCHYNODEID"]]
            existing_child["HVALUE"] += child_node["HVALUE"]
            if child_node["IDs"].empty():
                existing_child["IDs"].extend(None)
            else  
                existing_child["IDs"].extend(child_node["IDs"])  
        else:
            child_nodes[r['HIERARCHYNODEID']] = child_node
    if child_nodes:
        node.update(child_nodes)
    return node
```